# java datagram socket not received (localhost)

Tags: java, udp

This is a common issue, but I can't seem to make this work, it's not due to firewall, I made sure Intellij was authorized.

UDP SENDER:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    try {
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        int port = 9850;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 100, ip, port);

        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port, ip);
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   System.out.println("will send !");
                                   try {
                                       socket.send(packet);
                                   }catch (IOException e){
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                       return;
                                   }
                                   System.out.println("was sent !");
                               }
                           },500, 500);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }catch (UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

UDP RECEIVER

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = 8888;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, 100);

    try {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("ready to receive");
                socket.receive(packet);
                System.out.println("received a packet");
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }catch(SocketException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Packets are sent, the sender does display "will send/was sent" but the receiver doesn't receive anything, it's blocked and only displays "ready to receive"

ps: nevermind that sockets aren't closed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look carefully at the various calls to `DatagramSocket` and `DatagramPacket` that you are using, as you are misusing them.

In the Sender program, you are "construct[ing] a datagram packet for sending packets of length `length` to the specified port number on the specified host."  You're then "creat[ing] a datagram socket, bound to the specified local address".  As you're using the same port and `InetAddr`, you essentially are sending a packet to the same address you are listing to.

In the Receiver program, you "construct[] a datagram socket and bind[] it to the specified port on the local host machine."  This time, you are binding it to a different port than the one you are sending it to. (8888 vs 9850 where you are sending the packet to).

For the Sender, trying creating a socket which is bound to a random port, by calling `DatagramSocket()`.  For the receiver, change the socket so it is bound to the same numbered port that the sender is attempting to send it to (e.g. 9850)

Comment: If I understand, the port I add to a datagram socket is a source port, and the port I add to a datagram packet is the destination port.
While I can have **several** pointers which destination have the same port from the same machine, only **one** can listen to it.

I understand now why an exception was thrown before!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use while(true) because the method DatagramPacket.receive will  blocks until a datagram is received.

the cause of the problem may be the port that is different from one side to the other

Comment: using the same port will throw an exception,

the use of while(true) is artificial in this case, it was just for testing purpose

Comment: you send a packet to localhost port 9850 but no one is listening to the port

Comment: start the receiver with port 9850 and after that start the sender also with port 9850, it should work !

Comment: While your answer was not exhaustive I upvoted yours to counterbalance the downvote ;) you were right, though _dan.m was user2321368_'s answer was more helpful.

Comment: yes dan.m was user2321368 answer is mor clear i agree